# Why is the worst case time complexity for a Binary Tree Insert/Delete operation different than a Linked List?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

My understanding is that the worst case scenario for a binary tree is that it's completely unbalanced and equivalent to a linked list. However, when I look at a [time complexity chart](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/), it shows that the worst case for a Linked List Insert/Delete is O(1), while a Binary Tree is O(N).

Why would a Binary Tree be slower when it's worst case is supposed to resemble a linked list?

Comment: Is your linked-list sorted - or unsorted?

Comment: I don't understand why that'd be relevant for an insert.

Comment: When inserting into a sorted collection you need to ensure the collection is still sorted after adding new items. In a sorted linked-list that means `O(n)` for insert, not `O(1)` - and while in the worst-case a BST will also require `O(n)` to insert, in the average case it's `O(log n)` which beats the pants off sorted linked-lists.

Comment: Insert into a linked list can mean different things. If you know where you want to insert something and you have access to that node, then all you need to do is update the node to insert your new node. But if you also need to perform a search, to find e.g. the node at a specific index, then obviously this search will already cost you *O(n)*.

Comment: @Berthur Right - I had the same thought when I looked at the table on the linked-page, because it only has "Insertion" times - it doesn't consider "Append" (to end, unsorted) vs. "Insert" (at a specific place, or when sorted), which have very different complexities in Linked List vs. Trees.

Comment: That's where my confusion comes from. Since the site listed O(1) for the linked list insert, I assumed it ignores the cost of the search, and therefore the cost of the tree insert would also ignore the search and be O(1).

Comment: Notice also that in the source you mentioned, they analyse the Binary *Search* Tree, which is quite a stricter structure than just a Binary Tree.

Comment: But the part of finding where to insert the node would be handled in the search whose cost we ignore right? The insert operation should just involve changing some pointers like updating the next in a linked list insert.

Comment: @OccasionApple Do you have your copy of CRLS (any edition) to-hand? (see page 236 in the 3rd edition, where it makes the distinction between sorted and unsorted linked-lists).

Answer (score -1):

> Why is the worst case time complexity for a Binary Tree Insert/Delete operation different than a Linked List?

Because the page you linked to makes some assumptions...

- ...that linked-lists...

  - are *always unsorted*
  - always store a pointer to their end node and/or head node, as opposed to only just the head node.
  - define "inserting" as appending a new node to the end of the list, or prepending it to the head of the list, as opposed to inserting at a random location within the list.

    - conversely, it assumes BSTs define "inserting" such that it maintains sort-order (which is fair, as appending a node out-of-order would simply be incorrect).

> Why would a Binary Tree be slower when it's worst case is supposed to resemble a linked list?

A BST's worst-case insert op is slower than a linked-list's insert-op only when the linked-list is specifically optimized for inserting new items to the end of the list by holding a reference/pointer to the end node - but if the linked-list lacks such a feature then indeed it's as bad as a degenerate BST.

[Wikipedia's Linked list article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_lists) mentions that the runtime complexity of appending to the end of a linked-list is `O(n)` and not `O(1)` unless the linked-list maintains a reference to the terminal node:

> Appending one linked list to another can be inefficient unless a reference to the tail is kept as part of the List structure, **because we must traverse the entire first list in order to find the tail**, and then append the second list to this. Thus, if two linearly linked lists are each of length **n**, list appending has asymptotic time complexity of **O(n)**

(Appending one list to another is a more general-case of adding a single node to an existing list).

So, personally, I'd revise the table in the linked article to something like this (I'm aware I'm mixing best-case, avg-case, and worst-case in a single table):

| Data Structure | Operation | Time Complexity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Singly Linked List with only Head ptr | Append-to-end | **O(n)** |
| Singly Linked List with Head and End ptrs | Append-to-end | **O(1)** |
| **Sorted** Singly Linked List with Head and End ptrs | Insert new 50% value | **O(n)** |
| [Degenerate ascending BST](https://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Edurand/CS2/Notes/10_Binary_Trees/ds_treesB.html) | Insert new Maximum value | **O(n)** |
| Balanced BST | Inserting new Maximum value | **O(log n)** |

...so when those assumptions are considered, and when we require a singly linked list to *not* have an end-node ptr then its worst-case append is **O(n)** and not **O(1)**.

Comment: How do you get O(1) for inserting a new 50% value into a balanced BST? Doesn't that take O(log n)?

Comment: The page doesn't state those assumptions about linked lists, and the Wikipedia article it (and you) links to mentions that you can insert in constant time *anywhere*. If you just have a pointer to the insertion position. C++'s [list::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) for example also offers that.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, yes - that's a mistake... I'll correct that now - but I've been awake for 36 hours now and I can't sustain the mental agility to actually work out what the time complexity is so I'll just remove it :) - it wasn't even relevant to the question in the first place, I honestly don't know why I even put that there.